# Integration ZKTecho data with django project

Tags: integration, zk

"My machine's name is MB20 (ZKTECHO), and I want to integrate its data into my Django project. This machine runs on a local IP and port, but when I try to access the IP and port, I don't receive any data. Please guide me on how to integrate this data into my project."